# Saving LZW compression output?

Tags: python, compression, lzw

I am reading up on the LZW algorithm and I have an implementation like so;

```py
def compress(data):
    dictionary = {chr(i): i for i in range(256)}
    next_code = 256
    result = []
    sequence = ""

    for char in data:
        new_sequence = sequence + char

        if new_sequence in dictionary:
            sequence = new_sequence
        else:
            result.append(dictionary[sequence])
            dictionary[new_sequence] = next_code
            next_code += 1
            sequence = char

    if sequence:
        result.append(dictionary[sequence])

    return result


def decompress(data):
    dictionary = {i: chr(i) for i in range(256)}
    next_code = 256
    result = []

    sequence = chr(data[0])
    result.append(sequence)

    for code in data[1:]:
        if code in dictionary:
            entry = dictionary[code]
        elif code == next_code:
            entry = sequence + sequence[0]
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid compressed data")

        result.append(entry)
        dictionary[next_code] = sequence + entry[0]
        next_code += 1
        sequence = entry

    return "".join(result)
```

However the output from LZW is an array of integers. I'd assume if one wanted to use this in practice, you would instead want to use bytes as you can then save these bytes to disk. However when you now have an array of bytes, how would you then read these bytes to decompress?

tl;dr: How do you take the int array output from lzw, save and read it from disk as bytes?

Comment: @Brian61354270 That won't work for this, since the values are bigger than a byte.

Comment: Not really. In LZW, we don't store a list of hex values, but a list of integers. This means that it goes above 0xff. You will then get an error which says `struct.error: byte format requires -128 <= number <= 127`

Comment: Have you read the Wikipedia article?

Comment: I tried to read [this from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch#Example). However in here they use 5 and 6 bits. Also they appear to use different values. I.e., A = 1, B = 2, ...

Comment: I think I might have found a solution. Using [Huffman encoding](https://iq.opengenus.org/huffman-encoding/), I can store characters with less then one byte of space. I just gotta figure out how to apply it :)